# Making bibliography \flushbottom in book class

Tags: spacing, biblatex, book-design

I am using the book class and have a long bibliography (using Biblatex) at the end of each chapter. When there is a long reference around where a page break occurs, the whole reference shifts to the next page (good), but for aesthetic reasons I would like the separation between references on the full page to increase so that it is (`\flushbottom`)ed, matching up with the content of the book.

MWE (needs example bib file from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/examples)):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\title{Testing}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\nocite{aksin} \nocite{angenendt} \nocite{aristotle:anima} \nocite{aristotle:physics}
\nocite{aristotle:poetics} \nocite{aristotle:rhetoric} \nocite{augustine}
\nocite{averroes/bland} \nocite{averroes/hannes} \nocite{averroes/hercz}
\nocite{baez/article} \nocite{baez/online} \nocite{brandt}  \nocite{markey}
\nocite{knuth:ct:a} \nocite{knuth:ct:b} \nocite{knuth:ct:c} \nocite{knuth:ct:d}
\nocite{knuth:ct:e} \nocite{knuth:ct:related} \nocite{moraux} \nocite{sigfridsson}
 \nocite{westfahl:space} \nocite{nietzsche:historie} \nocite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\nocite{nietzsche:ksa} \nocite{wilde} \nocite{worman} \nocite{yoon}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would like the bottom of the Brandt reference to line up with the bottom of the Wilde reference, at the same height where pages 1 & 2 end. I haven't been able to find an option for this.

Comment: How many lines do some of the longer bib entries take up? Are we talking four of five lines, or eight or more lines? If it's the latter, letting LaTeX insert a page break in the middle of such an entry may well be the lesser of two evils, the other being forcing LaTeX to insert huge amounts of inter-entry whitespace to generate the desired flushbottom look.

Comment: Generally only up to 4-5 lines, yes, so the whitespace at the bottom is usually max 3-4 lines. I agree about breaking if they were a lot longer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to use a rubber length for `\bibitemsep`

```
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{12pt plus 10pt minus 10pt}   %% adjust this suitably
```

You have to adjust `plus 10pt minus 10pt` suitably at the end (for example give some more value).

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{12pt plus 10pt minus 10pt}
\title{Testing}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\nocite{aksin} \nocite{angenendt} \nocite{aristotle:anima} \nocite{aristotle:physics}
\nocite{aristotle:poetics} \nocite{aristotle:rhetoric} \nocite{augustine}
\nocite{averroes/bland} \nocite{averroes/hannes} \nocite{averroes/hercz}
\nocite{baez/article} \nocite{baez/online} \nocite{brandt}  \nocite{markey}
\nocite{knuth:ct:a} \nocite{knuth:ct:b} \nocite{knuth:ct:c} \nocite{knuth:ct:d}
\nocite{knuth:ct:e} \nocite{knuth:ct:related} \nocite{moraux} \nocite{sigfridsson}
 \nocite{westfahl:space} \nocite{nietzsche:historie} \nocite{nietzsche:ksa1}
\nocite{nietzsche:ksa} \nocite{wilde} \nocite{worman} \nocite{yoon}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The desired effect can be achieved by redefining `\bibsetup`, i.e.,

```
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\flushbottom}
```

According  to the manual `\bibsetup` contains

> Arbitrary code to be executed at the beginning of the bibliography, intended for commands which affect the layout of the bibliography.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to fill the space by splitting references over page breaks, rather than by increasing the vertical separation between references on that page. I'd prefer to avoid this because I have allowed DOIs and URLs to break over lines, and this would allow them to break over pages too.